# sending json from javascript to asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json

I have a web app where the backend is made in ASP.net. The ajax call is a normal get request

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'myurl/updatejson',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {
        // do something
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, err){
        console.error(xhr, status, err);
    }
});
```

Where data is a simple key, value object correctly formatted. The C# backend is

```
public HttpStatusCodeResult UpdateJson(Dictionary<string, object> json){ //do something }
```

from this i was expecting that `json` in c# would be equal to `key, value` but instead i get `key, [value]` for some reason. If i declare the Dictionary as `Dictionary<string, string>` instead of `Dictionary<string, object>` everything works fine and i  get the expected result, so it mean that for some reason is converting the string to object wrapping it in an array.

How can i use the `dictionary<string, object>` (because the value could be a string, int or boolean) without having the value wrapped in an array?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use dynamic type resolution ?

```
 public HttpResponseMessage UpdateJson([FromBody]dynamic value){
    ...
    Console.WriteLine(value["field1"]);
 }
```